# Including variable in file directory in matlab ..?

Tags: matlab

I want to access several sequenced folders

Example :

```
[ndata, text, alldata] = xlsread(' D: \ folder \ 1 \ file ' ) ;
[ndata, text, alldata] = xlsread(' D: \ folder \ 2 \ file ' ) ;
[ndata, text, alldata] = xlsread(' D: \ folder \ 3 \ file ' ) ;
[ndata, text, alldata] = xlsread(' D: \ folder \ 4 \ file ' ) ;
```

Could I replace 1,2,3and 4 by variable i .. How could the directory be written here ?!

Please need any recommendation !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Use the `sprintf()` command.

```
i=1;
[ndata, text, alldata] = xlsread(sprintf('D:\\folder\\%i\\file',i))
```

To make sure this is working right, change the sprintf to a fprintf, and make sure the file exists.

```
>> i=1;
>> fprintf('D:\\folder\\%i\\file',i)
D:\folder\1\file
>> ls D:\folder\1\file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your recommendation but unfortunately when I tested:  

 (sprintf('D:\folder\%i\file',i)    as a stand alone function the output is 

ans =

D:

Warning: See help sprintf for valid escape sequences.

Comment: It really works when I tried:

(sprintf('D:\\folder\\%i\\file',i)


Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @OceanBlue: Change the sprintf to an fprintf, and make sure the file is correct by doing something like an ls. The escape sequence was wrong (Per the error), so just change the single \'s to \\'s. And if you want to be really nice, please select one of the answers by selecting the check mark next to it:-)

Answer (score 2):

The `fullfile` command is meant for this purpose:

```
xlsread(fullfile('D:','folder', sprintf('%d',i) , 'file'));
```

The `fullfile` function takes care of OS-specific file separator and insuring only one file separator is used per folder division.  (i.e. `strcmp(fullfile('a','b')` equals `fullfile('a/','/b')`)

Answer (score 2):

```
[ndata, text, alldata] = xlsread([' D:/folder/' num2str(i) '/file ' ]) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use forward slashes, that works everywhere.

Don't make things harder than they should be.